# Only want one file uploaded to bucket but two files are being uploaded to bucket every time I upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Every time I upload a file to my bucket from my website two copies get uploaded. Is there anything wrong with my code that makes this happen?

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multers3 = require('multer-s3');
const path = require('path');  // Add this for file extension handling
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'MyAccessKeyId',
  secretAccessKey: 'MySecretKey',
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
  } else {
      cb('Error: Images Only!');
  }
};
const s3 = new aws.S3({});
module.exports = {
  uploadImage: multer({
      storage: multers3({
          s3: s3,
          bucket: 'my-bucket',
          acl: 'public-read',
          metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
              cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
          },
          key: (req, file, cb) => {
              const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
              cb(null, uniqueSuffix + '-' + file.originalname);
          },
      }),
      limits: { fileSize: 3 * 1024 * 1024 },  // 3 MB
      fileFilter: fileFilter,
  })
};
```

I have tried changing a few things but nothing has worked, are multer and multer 3 both uploading the same file to my bucket?

Comment: So the end result is two S3 objects in the same S3 bucket, with identical content, but with different keys?

Comment: Yes they both have different keys.

Comment: Can you insert some debugging statements to print information and then check the log file?

Comment: It has something to do with  uniqueSuffix, it seems to be creating two different keys for the same file, one when it is uploaded to the bucket and when the file gets retrieved to my website a copy of the file with a new key is created in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it was related to uniqueSuffix that was creating two different keys for when a file was uploaded to the bucket and when the same file was getting retrieved from the bucket. This created two different copies of the same file in my bucket. To overcome this and keep the files unique. I decided to use a key of originalfilename+userid+timestamp, excluding seconds to ensure the time between upload and retrival was the same and hence the key was the same for the file for both upload and retrieval.  Here is the code if anyone is interested.

````
             key: (req, file, cb) => {
                const userId = req.user._id;
                const isProfilePictureUpload = req.body.isProfilePictureUpload === 'true';
            
                if (isProfilePictureUpload) {
                    const filename = `profile_${userId}.${file.originalname.split('.').pop()}`;
                    cb(null, filename);
                } else {
                    // Use the original filename, user ID, and timestamp with days, hours, and minutes
                    const now = new Date();
                    const days = now.getDate();
                    const hours = now.getHours();
                    const minutes = now.getMinutes();
            
                    const timestamp = `${days}-${hours}-${minutes}`;
                    const filename = `${file.originalname}-${userId}-${timestamp}`;
                    cb(null, filename);
                }
            }, ```
````